# Compass doesn't recompile scss files on page load in Sinatra app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sinatra, sass, compass-sass, bootstrap-sass

I've created a sinatra app and I want to include Twitter Bootstrap using the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) gem.

Following the installation instructions in the bootstrap-sass readme under [Compass (no Rails)](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#b-compass-no-rails). After running `compass install bootstrap` the files get created and everything works fine.

However, when I make a change to my scss file (in `/views/sass/styles.scss`) and reload the page, the css file isn't recompiled. Am I under the false assumption a page request recompiles the scss file? If so: how do I get compass to auto-compile the scss file? If not: what am I doing wrong?

See my [github repo](https://github.com/flauwekeul/twentyfourseven) for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a bug in bootstrap-sass which was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/commit/4dfe097817e3f209732153de0df299b1f572d8b1).

Until this fix is merged into a stable version the master branch should be used:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'bootstrap-sass', git: 'https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass'
```

Run the app using `bundle exec ruby app.rb`.